# how to scroll parallel two uicollectionview in ObjC

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

i want to scroll both `UICollectionView` at same time. when i am scrolling first collection view then scroll bottom UIcollectionview (Collectionview2).

Currently i am using **scrollViewDidEndDecelerating** Method but it's not working properly.
please give any sugestion for that.

[image: see Image...]

Currently i am using following code...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
 CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake(self.clnViewWorkoutTitles.center.x + self.clnViewWorkoutTitles.contentOffset.x,
                                      self.clnViewWorkoutTitles.center.y + self.clnViewWorkoutTitles.contentOffset.y);
    NSIndexPath *centerCellIndexPath = [self.clnViewWorkoutTitles indexPathForItemAtPoint:centerPoint];
    [self.clnViewWorkoutContent scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:centerCellIndexPath.item inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    [self.clnViewWorkoutTitles scrollToItemAtIndexPath:centerCellIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];}
```

Comment: Can you show the current code you have?

Comment: @Otávio sure  please check i have updated the question.

Comment: I can see _cells_ on your screenshot; where is the first collection view? where is the second? what does _"not working properly"_ mean? how does it work? what do you expect instead?

Comment: @holex first collectionview is: clnViewWorkoutTitles and second collection view is clnViewWorkoutContent

Answer (score 1):

you can also use collectionview Delegates like if you are using two collection view collectionview.tag ==101 and collectionview.tag ==102.
in your first collectionview three cell are displaying

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSLog(@"%li",(long)indexPath.row);

if(collectionView.tag == 101){

    if(fmod(indexPath.row, 3) == 1 && indexPath.row != 1){

        if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionLeft) {
        [self.collectionView2 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currScrollXPos+300, 0) animated:YES];
        currScrollXPos = currScrollXPos+300;
        }
        if (scrollDirection == ScrollDirectionRight) {
            [self.collectionView2 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(currScrollXPos-300, 0) animated:YES];
            currScrollXPos = currScrollXPos-300;
        }
    }
```

}